# Automate jproflier profiling and saving sanpshots

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, performance-testing, jprofiler

We at our org do REST end point profiling manually and saving the snapshot then we analyze the same offline.
Is there any way / API to run the jprofiler automatically against any REST end point and save the snapshot in a place.

Also, can anyone know whether any other tool (dynatrace , yourkit) has these feature ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JProfiler this is called [offline profiling](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.offline). You either have to add triggers to the session configuration to automate recording and [save snapshots](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.snapshots), or you use the [profiling API](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/api/javadoc/com/jprofiler/api/agent/Controller.html) in your code.